# JQuery.ajax(): Issue with parameter data when consuming a WCF Service

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, jquery

I'm using JQuery to consume a WCF Service. Actually this works fine:

```
var para = ' { "Parameter" : { "ID" : "5", "Name" : "Peter" } }'
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: para,
   url: url
   success: success
});
```

But I don't want to pass the data parameter as String and I think it should be possible to pass ist as array in any way. Like that:

```
var para = { "Parameter" : { "ID" : 5, "Name" : "Peter" } }
```

But when I try this I'm getting an error. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var para = '{ "ID" : "5", "Name" : "Peter" }';
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: para,
   url: url
   success: success
});
```

If you format it like this you should be able to get the values as

```
$_POST will return array('ID' => '5', 'Name' => 'Peter');
```

but you can also access it by doing:

```
$_POST['ID'] and $_POST['Name']
```

Also you could make use of the jquery post function:

```
var para = '{ "ID" : "5", "Name" : "Peter" }';
$.post(
    url, 
    para
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) function from the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Then you ajax call will be

```
var para = { Parameter : { ID :5, Name : "Peter" } };
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: JSON.stringify(para),
   url: url
   success: success
});
```

The usage of manual conversion to the JSON string is not good because of possible spatial characterless in the string which must be escaped (see http://www.json.org/ for details).